How do you get binary data into a unit test for the Kotlin multiplatform `wasmJs` target?
I have a pure Kotlin multiplatform library which targets wasmJs in addition to other targets. Building the library works without problem but I have a problem getting the unit tests to work. The problem is that my unit tests require some data to be loaded as a ByteArray from a file (via kotlinx-io) and that doesn't seem to be supported for wasmJs. The question now is: how do you get such data into a unit test for the wasmJs target?

You can't test a capability in wasmJsTest that isn't also present in wasmJsMain.  I recommend building the test in the test location that matches your implementation.  For example, if you built the function that uses ByteArray in commonMain, you would build the tests in commonTest

@RobertJamison That's what I do already. I have the feature class in commonMain and the test class in commonTest but how can I read the binary test data if there is no way to access the file system?
